# Write to console using Filewriter in java

Tags: java, console, filewriter

I got problem in java. I need to use FileWriter to write output. But now i want to use Filewriter to write standard output( to console). Have any ideas?? 
Thanks for your helping

Comment: Nomen est omen. **File**Writer.

Comment: Who has given you this patently ridiculous requirement and why?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen stdout (also stderr and stdin) can be identified and written to like any normal file via a filedescriptor. And that's actually just what java does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.FileDescriptor)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by initializing the `FileWriter` with a `FileDescriptor` via the constructor [`FileWriter#FileWriter(FileDescriptor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.FileDescriptor))

A quick example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FileDescriptor.out);
        fw.write("Hello world\n");
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Outputs

> Hello world